# Creating a chrome:// page for my Firefox add-on

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building a simple Firefox add-on using the [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK), and I need it to display some information when first ran.

I don't want to rely on an external URL for this, so I figured that my best option is to use the `chrome://` scheme.

I have two questions

1. How to create said page?
2. Is it possible to pass a value to it (something along the lines of `welcome.html?key=abc`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [register](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration) a `content` or `resource` url scheme in `chrome.manifest`. You will be able to use `window.location` object there as usual.

Comment: I don't have a `chrome.manifest` in my extension. I am not sure, but I have not seen any mention of it in the current Add-on SDK (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @SilviuG nothing prevents you from adding it, does it?

Comment: Sweet! It works as advertised. Passing values using a query string works too. Do you know if it is possible to get a value that was previously stored in the `simple-storage` module from a `content` or `resource` page?

Comment: @SilviuG you can import `require` by doing `const { require } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/require.js");` but that is not the end of it since many APIs including `simple-storage` are scoped for a specific extension (based on `self`). You need access to your extension's [loader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage#Accessing_storage_from_the_console) there. You could try [faking it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/_loader#.40loader.2Foptions) but messaging would probably be a better approach.

Comment: Doesn't quite work. If I try to import `require` from a `chrome://myextension/content/welcome.html` page, I get a `ReferenceError: Cu is not defined` in the console. I'll keep digging. Thanks!

Comment: @SilviuG Cu is `Components.utils`